# How to find weblogic t3 adminurl

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I have a weblogic folder, From this - How can i find the adminurl that I can use with the below command

```
java weblogic.Deployer –adminurl t3://server:7001 –username system –password weblogic –listapps
```

I tried looking into setupinfo.txt, portlist.ini - but somehow this did not help/work. How can get this working?

I get errors/exceptions like these (after few attempts)

```
The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object 
Unable to connect to 'http://server:7001': Destination unreachable; java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: 1 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: localhost port: 7102; No available router to destination
```

based on setupinfo.txt, I am able to login to the web console - but I need to know how to get this command working with adminurl !!!

Thanks,

Comment: Can you find the config directory under the admin domain home? It may not be under the application home directory. Or search for config.xml?

Comment: Found it @startscript.xml, thanks Alex.  Steps 1) find startscript.xml  2) set listen-port-enabled to true 3) the same can be done by web console UI ... Admin Console Login to AdminConsole->Server->Configuration->ListenPort (enable and note down the port) Bingo. –  Muthuveerappan 20 mins ago

Answer (score 4):

Got it, thanks Alex.

Steps

- Find startscript.xml under your weblogic domain , search this file for "ADMIN_URL"
- The same can be done by web console UI ..... Admin Console Login to       AdminConsole->Server->Configuration->ListenPort (enable and note down the port)

Bingo.